# Django: NoReverseMatch at /courses/2/

Tags: django

**Getting this error:**

> ```
> Reverse for 'step' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'course_pk': 2, 'step_pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['courses/(?P<course_pk>\\d+)/(?P<step_pk>\\d+)/']
> ```

**/urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls', namespace='courses')),
...
```

**/courses/urls.py**

```
...
url(r'(?P<course_pk>\d+)/(?P<step_pk>\d+)/$', views.step_detail, name='step'),
...
```

**Error during template rendering:**
The html line generating the error is:

```
...
 <a href=" {% url 'courses:step' course_pk=step.course.pk step_pk=step_pk %} ">{{ step.title }}</a> 
...
```

**courses/models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**courses/views.py**

```
def course_detail(request, pk):
    # course = Course.objects.get(pk=pk)
    course =  get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk) 
    return render(request, "courses/course_detail.html", {"course": course})


def step_detail(request, course_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    return render(request, "courses/step_detail.html", {"step": step})
```

I can't seem to understand where the problem is as I'm currently new to Django. Much help would be appreciated.

Comment: step_pk=step.pk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
    <a href=" {% url 'courses:step' course_pk=step.course.pk step_pk=step_pk %} ">
```

Here step_pk = step_pk is not working. Step_pk is not defined because you did not return any information about step_pk in def course_detail at this line:

```
      return render(request, "courses/course_detail.html", {"course": course})
```

pass step inside return and use step_pk = step.pk

Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I, it was suppose to be step_pk = step.pk. Thank you for quick reply, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
{% url 'courses:step' course_pk=step.course.pk step_pk=step.pk %}
```

`step.pk` instead of `step_pk` which doesnot exist in your context

Comment: Thank you. I went through the code and did like you suggested. Much appreciated.